# Where all can the /*+ PARALLEL */ hint be used?

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-11g-r2, hints

It works with SELECT and UPDATE statements.

Are there some more statements with which it works?

I was able to use it with create, but am not sure if the hint was actually considered.

```
SQL> create /*+ PARALLEL */ table t1
( id number,
name varchar2(40));

Table created.

SQL>
```

Except INSERT and UPDATE, when all is the PARALLEL hint considered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Data Warehousing Guide has a chapter on parallel operations that goes over [what operations can be parallelized](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/usingpe.htm#DWHSG024).

You can't parallel-ize a simple CREATE TABLE statement (nor would you want to-- there wouldn't be enough work to be able to parcel it out to multiple worker threads).  You can, however, parallel-ize a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement either by specifying the PARALLEL hint in the SELECT or by [using the PARALLEL keyword in the CREATE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#sthref2219).

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can effectively do "CREATE /*+PARALLEL(8)*/ INDEX ..." to create an index in parallel without leaving the index enabled for parallel query afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

Oracle supports parallel processing for a wide range of operations, including queries, DDL, and DML:

1. Queries that involve table or index range scans
2. Bulk insert, update, or delete operations
3. Table and index creation
4. The collection of object statistics using `DBMS_STATS`
5. Backup and recovery operations using Recovery Manager (RMAN)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's just a generic statement about Oracle's parallel capabilities, not a specific answer about where the parallel hint can be used.